# How to solve this Specified value has invalid CRLF characters?

Tags: xml, api, post

I have an issue in POST XML data to External API URL
I got Error is System.ArgumentException: 'Specified value has invalid CRLF characters.
Please advice me
Thank you

```
    Dim url = "https://gold.mxpress2u.net/gold/API.asmx"
    Dim httpRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
    httpRequest.Method = "POST"
    httpRequest.ContentType = "application/xml"
    httpRequest.Accept = "application/xml"

    Dim data = Me.txtXML.Text
    httpRequest.Headers("strAPIKey") = "API Key"
    httpRequest.Headers("strCustomerAccount") = "Account No"
    httpRequest.Headers("intPrintFormatType") = "1"
    httpRequest.Headers("strShipmentDetailsXML") = data

'' After debug the error is on "httpRequest.Headers("strShipmentDetailsXML") = data"
'' Error is System.ArgumentException: 'Specified value has invalid CRLF characters.

    Dim streamWriter = New StreamWriter(httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
    If True Then
        streamWriter.Write(data)
    End If
    Dim httpResponse = CType(httpRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    Dim streamReader = New StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
    If True Then
        Dim result = streamReader.ReadToEnd()
    End If
    Console.WriteLine(httpResponse.StatusCode)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't put content that contains a carriage return in an HTTP header.

In fact, you shouldn't be putting values in HTTP headers anyway.

Looking at the documentation page, the API expects HTTP post parameters, not HTTP header values. See this example from the HTTP Post example, in the Create Shipment method.

```
POST /gold/API.asmx/CreateShipmentCN HTTP/1.1
Host: gold.mxpress2u.net
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: length

strAPIKey=string&strCustomerAccount=string&intPrintFormatType=string&strShipmentDetailsXML=string
```